# Pulling Android dependency in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to write a React Native version of this module https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

It is deprecated, but until we can transition to Braintree, we need the functionality for an existing app.

It has a dependency:

```
repositories{
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0') {
      exclude group: 'io.card'
   }
}
```

I would think that I should add this to the build.gradle file for the React Native app, but when I go there, I see this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

So it seems like I should have a build.gradle file in my module directory, which I do - the same as the one above (com.paypal.sdk...)

However, it doesn't seem to be registering.

Is there a way to indicate to download this dependency? I know in iOS there is pod install - is there an equivalent method in Android?

How do I install this dependency?

EDIT: My newest plugin build.gradle is this, and it still throws an error due to the library being missing:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

Comment: i think you can just add `compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0')` to your `app/build.gradle` dependencies?

Comment: Have I've tried similar and still had an error. I'll update my question with my new build.gradle